# what is the key binding name in xcode for searching classes in current file?

Tags: xcode

What is the keybinding name for the action taken when clicking the breadcrumb shown in this screenshot? This shows a searchable list of the classes in the current file.

[image: class search]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its name is Standard Editor->Show Document items. Default binding is ctrl-6. The breadcrumb prior to it is ctrl-5. You can change in Preferences->Key Bindings, under View Menu section.

Answer (score 1):

To specifically open that breadcrumb you can use ctrl-6 and search by typing.

You can also use Open Quickly to search for symbols in Xcode, which is cmd-shift-O

Open Quickly has support for partial-case and position insensitive matching so it's very flexible in searching through your code and files.